# dataWithEPSInsideRect not coming up as vector?

Tags: objective-c, vector, drawing, nsview, eps

I'm using these lines of code for an export of a vector PDF and this works fine:

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1700.0, 1700.0)];
                    myView.dataString = [dataText stringValue];
                    NSData *data = [myView dataWithPDFInsideRect:myView.bounds];
                    export = data;
```

However when I use essentially the same for EPS it create the EPS file however it's put a raster image of the view on layed on top of the the EPS file rather than all the elements in vector format as it does for PDF any ideas why?

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1700.0, 1700.0)];
                    myView.dataString = [dataText stringValue];
                    NSData *data = [myView dataWithEPSInsideRect:myView.bounds];
                    export = data;
```

Here is the difference from how they render for reference:

[image]

Comment: In the EPS file, is there a bitmap *in addition* to the vector content, or only bitmap content altogether? It's been ages since I've dealt with EPS, but IIRC, even vector-based EPS files would save a low-res bitmap preview of the content along with it so that apps like QuarkXPress or other page layout apps could display that since they didn't support EPS natively?

Comment: I believe the text is displayed as vector however the drawing is rendered as a low res bitmap. PDF is working fine which is weird as I would have thought the methods would work in a similar way.